# MUI textfield value not changing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to make a simple curd application using React + Material-UI (MUI). I have this page which has a table with some values and an edit button which on click opens a MUI dialogue box and populates the table row value in textfield.

Here is the code for the page:

```
const [modalopen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

const [modalProps, setModalProps] = useState<{ title: string; focusedTxtField: boolean; client: Client | null; }>({
  title: '',
  focusedTxtField: false,
  client: null,
});

const onModalClose = () => {
  setModalOpen(false)
  setModalProps({
    ...modalProps,
    title: '',
    focusedTxtField: false,
    client: null,
  });
};
  
const addModalHandle = () => {
  setModalProps({
    ...modalProps,
    title: 'Add Client',
    focusedTxtField: false,
    client: null,
  });
  setModalOpen((prev) => !prev);
};

const editModalHandle = (client: Client) => {
  setModalProps({
    ...modalProps,
    title: 'Edit Client',
    focusedTxtField: true,
    client: client,
  });
  setModalOpen((prev) => !prev);
};

return (
  <Box>
    <AddClientModal
      config={modalProps}
      handleClose={onModalClose}
      status={modalopen}
    />
```

Now the problem I am facing is when I open the dialogue box and click on a texfield and close the dialogue box, then again click edit button on a different row, the dialogue box opens but the value from the previous row is retained on the textfield I clicked before and it changes back to the new value only if I click on the textfield again.

Here is the code for the dialogue box:

```
<Dialog  fullWidth open={props.status} onClose={props.handleClose}>
  <DialogTitle
    color={'white'}
    bgcolor={'rgb(51, 171, 159)'}
    borderBottom={0.1}
  >
    {props.config.title}
  </DialogTitle>
  <Box component='form' noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitClient)}>
    <DialogContent>
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin='dense'
        label='Client Name'
        type='name'
        fullWidth
        focused={props.config.focusedTxtField}
        value={props.config.client?.name !== '' ?props.config.client?.name : ''}
        variant='standard'
        {...register('name', {
          required: 'Enter Client Name',
          pattern: {
            value: /^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i,
            message: 'Enter a valid Name',
          },
        })}
      />
```

I am unable to figure out what is happening. What I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Where is `register` comming from?

Comment: @konrad its from react-use-hook-form library

Comment: Why do you have both `value` prop and `register`? You should see the value through `react-hook-form`